# how hibernate can work without JPA specification

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I was working on project which did not have `JPA`, however it uses `Hibernate`
could anyone please explain how?

The project's `pom.xml`:

```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
       <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: It can work simply by using non standard annotations/classes, please note that hibernate existed already for many years before JPA has been specified

Comment: Or you mean that you use JPA in your project and you don't know how it is possible since you did not add the JPA API in your dependencies, it is what you meant?

Comment: what do you mean by saying hibernate existed before JPA?
Hibernate has its own specification?
entity classes have import javax.persistence.Entity; does it mean that we use JPA?

Comment: @M.T Hibernate doesn't need JPA, but JPA needs Hibernate or another JPA implementation to work. If you're using `javax.persistence.*`, then you're using (at least partially) JPA. JPA was also very heavily influenced by Hibernate, which was at the time probably the most popular ORM.

Comment: thank you guys appreciate it. To make it clear final question how I use JPA 
(import javax.persistence.Entity;) if I did not include it in pom.xml?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hibernate is a JPA implementation, meaning that when you're using JPA you could be using Hibernate, EclipseLink or any of the other implementations but you would code according to JPA specs, i.e. using `javax.persistence.*` interfaces, usually avoiding using implementation specific features (although that's still possible).

If you're coding directly with Hibernate, you would use only its specific classes (i.e. `org.hibernate.*`) and ways, and have no reference to `javax.persistence` anywhere.

It's similar to `JDBC`. You could write code that uses driver specific classes (and sometimes, but not often, there are valid reasons why you need to), but there are classes which implement the JDBC interfaces (`Connection`, `ResultSet`, `Statement` etc.) so you can write regular JDBC code without having to learn things again when you switch to a different database.

Comment: strange we did not include JPA in pom.xml but in entity classes I have this annotation import javax.persistence.Entity;

Comment: You don't need to include JPA separately. It's included in Java EE (well, Hibernate libs also need to have copies of the entities since it implements them). You can also use many of the annotations interchangeably, i.e. Hibernate has it's own `@Entity` annotation, but you can also use the one from JPA and it'll be the same.